# MySQL how do I correct this subquery?

Tags: mysql, select, join, subquery

I have the following table:

```
select * from points
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
| NAME    | TITLE             | Type | RANK |
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
| A       | Hippo             | H    |  1   |
| A       | Hippo             | M    |  1   |
| A       | Hippo             | H    | N/A  |
| A       | Hippo             | H    |  1   |
| A       | Hippo             | H    | N/A  |
| B       | Snail             | H    |  1   |
| B       | Snail             | M    |  1   |
| B       | Snail             | L    |  1   |
| C       | Dog               | H    |  1   |
| C       | Dog               | M    |  1   |
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
```

**Desired output**

```
+---------+----------+-------+
| NAME    | TITLE    | SCORE |
+---------+----------+-------+
| A       | Hippo    |   60  | <--[(2xH)=40 + (1xM)=20] =60
| B       | Snail    |  100  | <--[(1xH)=70 + (1xM)=20 + (1xL)=10] =100
| C       | Dog      |  100  | <--This should happen because [(1xH)=80 + (1xM)=20] =100
+---------+----------+-------+
```

**Computations required:**

- Type can have only three values: {H, M, L};
- When all values are present, they are graded as followed:

  **H=70 M=20 L=10**
- If an name has more than one kind of Type (H, M, or L) then points are distributed as followed:
- **H/(number of H) ; M/(number of M); L/(number of L) = 100**

-- Example: A has 4 H therefore 70 / 4 = 17.5 for each H

But some names have a complete set with out having all 'Types.
-- example : C has Type values: 'H&M` only

- CASE H&M

**H=80 M=20**

- CASE M&L

**M=60 L=40**

- CASE H&L

**H=90 L=10**

And also

- if only H is presnet **H=100**
- if only M is presnet **M=100**
- if only L is presnet **L=100**

Comment: Where do these 40, 20, 70, 20, 10 values come from?

Comment: @ypercube crap I hosed the info on an edit

Comment: Well, I don't see it. Or, in other words, I don't get why (for type H for eample) Hippos get 40, Snails get 70 and Dogs get 80.

Comment: Ok, this is interesting, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you want:

```
SELECT name,
       title,
       CAST(
       (      -- only have H, or only have M, or only have L:
         CASE WHEN  `# of H` = 0  AND  `# of M` = 0  THEN  100 * `# of active L` / `# of L`
              WHEN  `# of H` = 0  AND  `# of L` = 0  THEN  100 * `# of active M` / `# of M`
              WHEN  `# of M` = 0  AND  `# of L` = 0  THEN  100 * `# of active H` / `# of H`
              -- only have H & M, or only have H & L, or only have M & L:
              WHEN  `# of H` = 0  THEN  60 * `# of active M` / `# of M` + 40 * `# of active L` / `# of L`
              WHEN  `# of M` = 0  THEN  0  -- ??????????
              WHEN  `# of L` = 0  THEN  80 * `# of active H` / `# of H` + 20 * `# of active M` / `# of M`
              -- have all three:
              ELSE  70 * `# of active H` / `# of H` + 20 * `# of active M` / `# of M` + 10 * `# of active L` / `# of L`
         END
       ) AS SIGNED ) AS score
  FROM ( SELECT name,
                title,
                SUM(IF(         type = 'H', 1, 0))  AS `# of H`,
                SUM(IF(rank AND type = 'H', 1, 0))  AS `# of active H`,
                SUM(IF(         type = 'M', 1, 0))  AS `# of M`,
                SUM(IF(rank AND type = 'M', 1, 0))  AS `# of active M`,
                SUM(IF(         type = 'L', 1, 0))  AS `# of L`,
                SUM(IF(rank AND type = 'L', 1, 0))  AS `# of active L`
           FROM points
          GROUP
             BY name,
                title
       ) t
 ORDER
    BY name
;
```

Comment: Thanks greatly for the response ruakh. You were right that was a typo on my part. Thanks for picking that up. What does '`# of H`' do/return? Or is that pseudo code? I've never seen or used that syntax before in MySQL

Comment: @Gah_Jamn-it: It's just a name. Just like how a column can be named `title`, a column can be named `` `# of H` ``. (Because of the special characters, it has to be wrapped in backticks `` ` `` so that MySQL can tell where it starts and ends.)

Comment: Ruakh Even if a 'Rank' is N/A, that entry will still need to be accounted for. Hence, if you have three 'Bird' entries and all of Bird 'type' eqaul H ( Hence: 3 x H) and their 'Ranks' are as follows 1, N/A, and N/A. The Birds score should be be 100/3 = 33.3 for each Rank. And since only one rank is active (hence 1) the score will be 33.3

Comment: @Gah_Jamn-it: What if there are two Bird entries: one H that has rank = N/A and one M that has rank = 1?

Comment: that would be case 'H' 'M' -->  H=80/1 M=20/1 & Since only M is 1 (active) then the results would be (80*0)+(20*1)=20

Comment: @Gah_Jamn-it: O.K., I think I understand now. Maybe. I've updated my answer.

Comment: You did it! Thanks ruakh. genius